# "AWT-Windows" java.lang.InternalError: unsupported screen depth

Tags: android, docker, android-studio, gradle, teamcity

I am trying to perform a clean build of an aAndroid Studio build with Build Agents in Teamcity, but as it builds, it hangs on a error
Exception in thread "AWT-Windows" java.lang.InternalError: unsupported
screen depth at sun.awt.windows.WToolkit.init(Native Method) at         sun.awt.windows.WToolkit.run(WToolkit.java:301) at     java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)